# Make a button on visualforce update the records in an object

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I have a custom object named "O1". It have 5 fields, namely

1.) Address

2.) Name

3.) Email

4.) Phone Number

5.) Age

I have created a custom VF page and shown these fields on that page. Now, I want to assign a save button which will save the data entered by user here into the object "O1".

How can I do so? Is it called anything? I can look it up myself, just need someone to point me in right direction.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are all fields that live directly on your custom object, then you can just use the standard controller on your custom object, and then invoke the standard {!save} function on a commandButton/link/etc

**Something like this... (Note, have not attempted to compile code, wrote on the fly):**

```
<apex:page standardController="O1__c">
    <apex:PageBlock>
        <apex:PageBlockSection>
            <apex:form>
                <apex:inputField value="{!O1__c.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!O1__c.Email__c}" />
                ... etc
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            </apex:form>
        </apex:PageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:Page>
```

**See the Salesforce Documentation on StandardController Methods for more information on all methods available when using standardController:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm

Comment: I am already doing this. But, it only refreshes the page. doesn't save the input

Comment: Is your commandButton inside the same <apex:form> as your form fields? If your button doesn't live inside of the same form, it won't save any of the data in that form. Salesforce should commit all changes on the page before invoking Save, so thats my best guess without seeing your code.

Comment: I just checked and my button was indeed outside my `form`. Thank you.

Comment: Nice, glad that worked out for you!